# Solve a special Differential Equation of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How we can solve the following  Differential Equation of second order :

$$2y(t)\cos(t)-y^{'}\sin(t)+y^{''}\cos(t)=\alpha$$
such that $\alpha$ is a constant not equals to zeros, and $y$ is a $C^{2}-$smooth  $2\pi-$periodic function

Comment: Plugging this into WA suggests the solution is not so great..

Comment: May use series expansion?

Answer (score 1):

$$2y(t)\cos(t)-y^{'}\sin(t)+y^{''}\cos(t)=0$$
$y_1(t)= \sin t$ is an obvious solution:
$$2\sin t \cos(t)-\cos t \sin(t)-\sin t\cos(t)=0$$
You can reduce the order. Substitute:
$$y(t)=y_1 v(t)=\sin t v(t)$$